# Make text stick to the bottom of a HTML div with CSS

Tags: html, css

Quick and easy question. I'd like to have a floating box that stays in the bottom right of a div (in HTML). How would I do this with css?
 Thanks! (attached is what I want it to look like)[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)) / What do you expect? / What error do you get? **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will be what you are looking for.

```
   .navBar {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: blue;
    }

    .div1 {
      position: relative;
      height: 200px;
    }

    .div1 .box {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 40px;;
        right: 40px;;
        width: 200px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .div2 {
      height: 100px;
      background: green;
    }

    <div class="main-container">
      <div class="navBar"></div>
      <div class="div1"><div class="box"></div></div>
      <div class="div2"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

what you're looking for is:
`position:absolute;
bottom:0;
right:0;` which will position things relative to the positioned parent.Note that the parent element (div) needs to have its position set as well. Most people do `position:relative;`
The values `bottom:0` and `right:0` means to move it 0px away from the bottom of the parent and 0 px away from the right side of the parent.
See the following w3schools for further information:

1. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp
2. https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_absolute